# Don't run python project Silero libary

Tags: python

i'm don't run my project with libar Silero plz help me!!!!!!
my code:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import time

language = 'ua'
model_id = 'ua_v3'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'baya_v2'
put_accent = True
put_yoo = True
device = torch.device('cpu')
text = "Привіт!"

model, _= torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                       model='silero_tts',
                                       language=language,
                                       speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)

audio = model.apply_tts(text=text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent=put_accent,
                        put_yoo=put_yoo)

print(text)

sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
time.sleep( len(audio) / sample_rate )
sd.stop()
```

when i'm run main.py enter error:

```
Using cache found in 
C:\Users\Private/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Private\Desktop\AntonVoiceHelper\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    model, _= torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
  File "C:\Users\Private\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 404, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Private\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py", line 433, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Private/.cache\torch\hub\snakers4_silero-models_master\src\silero\silero.py", line 73, in silero_tts
    assert speaker in available_speakers, f'Speaker not in the supported list {available_speakers}'
AssertionError: Speaker not in the supported list ['ru_v3', 'aidar_v2', 'aidar_8khz', 'aidar_16khz', 'baya_v2', 'baya_8khz', 'baya_16khz', 'irina_v2', 'irina_8khz', 'irina_16khz', 'kseniya_v2', 'kseniya_8khz', 'kseniya_16khz', 'natasha_v2', 'natasha_8khz', 'natasha_16khz', 'ruslan_v2', 'ruslan_8khz', 'ruslan_16khz', 'lj_v2', 'lj_8khz', 'lj_16khz', 'thorsten_v2', 'thorsten_8khz', 'thorsten_16khz', 'tux_v2', 'tux_8khz', 'tux_16khz', 'gilles_v2', 'gilles_8khz', 'gilles_16khz', 'aigul_v2', 'erdni_v2', 'dilyara_v2', 'dilnavoz_v2', 'mykyta_v2', 'multi_v2']
```

can you help or did I just enter the speaker incorrectly?
help !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Read your code again, but carefully: `torch.hub.load( ... speaker=model_id)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.